# I run AWS commands within Github actions, I want all AWS API calls to be ran against a dummy. Any ideas on how to do this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, github-actions, aws-cli

I have following workflow called:
deploy_to_AWS.yml

Within that yml I am using: (to configure the account I am pointing at)

```
      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        id: config-aws-creds
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.THIS_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.THIS_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: eu-west-2
```

After that I have many different awscli commands e.g.:

```
      - name: Run cron ecs
        run: |
          subnets=`aws ssm get-parameter --name "xxx_ecs_subnet" | jq -r '.Parameter.Value'`
          security_group=`aws ssm get-parameter --name "xxx_ecs_security_group_id" | jq -r '.Parameter.Value'`
          aws ecs run-task --cluster xxx-cluster --task-definition xxx-cron --count 1 --launch-type FARGATE --network-configuration "awsvpcConfiguration={subnets=[$subnets],securityGroups=[$security_group]}"
```

I want to use this tool: (https://github.com/nektos/act) to run the Github actions locally but I do not want real AWS calls to be made. I have had experience with a python library called moto in the past but I do not think this will work with the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to optionally pass in the "--dry-run" flag using a parameter or setting that only gets added when you are running locally?

Comment: the --dry-run flag is not available for all AWSCLI commands :/